# Getting an error, "Unprintable cloud error exception" while creating Azure VM via python sdk

Tags: python-3.x, azure, virtual-machine

On creating an Azure vm using Python sdk, I'm getting the error :
msrestazure.azure_exceptions.CloudError:

When I'm printing the CloudError, it throws another error :
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 643: ordinal not in range(128)

Can someone please help me out in this?

Comment: Could you please provide your code and the sdk version you use?

Comment: @JimXu I'm using Azure Az for Python 3.7 (sdk 2.0.0)

Comment: credentials, subscription_id = get_credentials()
        resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
        compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
        network_client = NetworkManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
        nic = create_nic(network_client)
        vm_parameters = create_vm_parameters(nic.id, VM_REFERENCE[OS_NAME])
        async_vm_creation = compute_client.virtual_machines.create_or_update(GROUP_NAME, VM_NAME, vm_parameters)
        async_vm_creation.wait()

Comment: Sorry. I cannot understand `Azure Az for Python 3.7 (sdk 2.0.0)`. Could you please provide requirements.txt or pip install command?

Comment: @JimXu pip install azure

Comment: Is that you use the command `pip install azure==2.0.0` to install sdk?

Comment: Have you referred tp https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/azure-sdk-example-virtual-machines?tabs=cmdto

Comment: @JimXu yes, thats the command. And, the link also pretty much elaborates the steps i took.

Comment: According to my test, I cannot reproduce your issue. It is Ok for me.

Comment: @JimXu im not sure why the error is in unprintiable format. I'm not able to know what's causing the error itself..

Comment: Could you please tell me how you print error and the error message?

Comment: @JimXu I'm just using a try and except block. and printing the error in the except block..

Comment: You can use `raise` to throw the exception to get the exception message.

Comment: @JimXu "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 643: ordinal not in range(128)" is the exception message i'm getting

Comment: Have you tried to decode the error message before you print?

Comment: @JimXu I've tried changing the encoding of the script. Please let me know if you have a better solution..